# Session saving problem, getting PHP Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, magento

Ok so I have written an integration to a third party order management solution inside of the Magento Ecommerce platform, which is built on top of the Zend Framework. Everything has worked fine on my local machine and also on my local dev server. Both Servers use PHP 5.2.x. When deploying to the Staging server which uses PHP 5.3.3 I am now getting this error in a part of my code

PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

I have tried  commenting out pieces of code to see where I can narrow it down to but with not that great of luck. I start the code in a Magento observer which calls a Model that I created that sets some variables in the Session as well. I have a lot of methods calling other classes such as my observer calls my Order Model, which that also calls my Customer Model and all of them call a few different methods inside of their classes. Its been kind of hard to debug this on the server by logging and commenting out lines, I am not making good progress.

From the research I have done, this seems to me more like something that I am trying to set to the session is dieing in the destructor. I tried using  session_write_close() at the end of my observer method before it returns, so that it might show me the error earlier on but it actually made my program not die and it worked like it was suppose to. I am not sure I am comfortable leaving that in there because I am sure it could mess the rest of the flow up but I am not that knowledgeable about this.

I am just trying to figure out what the best way to debug this is. I don't get why it works when putting that in there and what might be dieing in the destructor, obviously I am not throwing a exception in a destructor, but something I am doing is. But it has worked fine until I put the code on the Staging server. Which by the way is also using nginx instead of apache as well.

Comment: Why don't you use Zend_Session ? since your doing it in zend framework why not go out the whole way with it :)

Comment: I am using Magento's session Models.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, these things are hard to debug. I think the problem lays in serialization. Before an object is stored in the session, it will be serialized so it can be stored.

In an other project I've had this problem and got the same error messag as you have.

Magento has a couple of classes which can't be serialized. One of those classes is Mage_Core_Config_Element. Perhaps you make use of that class?

I'm not sure but perhaps if you create a custom serialize() function you can find the problem.

Comment: I guess now, the thing to do is maybe go through and one by one comment out each thing I am trying to save to the session and see what might be doing it. I just don't get why it only doesn't work on the one server.

Comment: Big difference between 5.2 and 5.3. Any particular reason you are developing on 5.2 while the production/staging is 5.3?

Comment: hmm I think I found it, I am trying to save an address object to the session and I think that is doing it. Anyway to make sure the object is set in the session correctly? I am using 5.2 because we usually have always done Magento on 5.2 but recently have a new host that switched us to 5.3 and I realize now I need to change. I am on a Mac and have 10.5 leopard and used the entropy.php.

Comment: I still don't know what to do, I have found the problem with I think the address object that I am saving to the session but I don't know why its dieing or what to do to fix this.

Comment: To fix it, I just stored the addresses data array instead of the whole object, still not sure the cause of being able to store the whole object.